# Please help me kill nautilus on root window

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gnome-panel

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and do not want nautilus to start running at all.  There used to be a way to kill it via gconf-editor.  Does anyone have the secret recipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [gnome-tweak-tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install acetoneiso] and then, under Desktop, you can disable "Have file manager handle the desktop".